# Android Camera intent doesn't return/locks up

Tags: android, camera, android-intent, image, freeze

I'm trying to take a picture from the Camera using intent with `onActivityResult` but every time I take a picture the camera locks up and never returns. Any reason why this might happen? This is the code I'm using:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.v(TAG,"Camera callback: "+Integer.toString(resultCode));
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        try{
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Log.v("Picture view",data.getData().toString());
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);  
            setContentView(image);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "something happened");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the LogCat output after taking a picture:

```
06-12 19:46:03.881: VERBOSE/camera(443): Start autofocus.
06-12 19:46:04.521: VERBOSE/camera(443): doSnap: mFocusState=1
06-12 19:46:04.721: VERBOSE/camera(443): mAutoFocusTime = 790ms
```

Then it just locks up and `onActivityResult` never fires.

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read a bunch of tutorials and everyone does it different. The official Android Docs use the [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)-class (step by step tutorial on the linked page).

I found [this other tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222151624/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/10/take-picture-in-android-with.html) (which uses the `MediaStore`-class, like you), but put an extra for the Output-File on the Intent.

You might want to check both of this tutorials and see if one works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lukas. The thing is, this happens randomly sometimes it'll work and sometimes it won't. When it locks up, I have to force stop the Camera, and if I try again it'll complain that the Camera service is not available. I will look into the links you posted and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with your Device/the Emulator? Have you tried different Devices?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the emulator sometimes I have to relaunch it 2-3 times before it works. Anyways, thanks for the help Lukas.